# custom fields not displaying on wordpress site

Tags: plugins, custom-field, themes, advanced-custom-fields

So I have all the fields created for the home page and I have fields created for (icons, contact form and etc...). I am having trouble displaying the contact form on my page. Like the field is done. I have retrieved all the necessary fields however, it's not displaying. *Note there is no code involved. I did not code at all. It was through a plugin called Advanced Custom Fields*. All I want to do is display the contact form that was created in the fields and display it on the contact us page.

Like see I am getting the necessary fields from the contact group right, but when I go to display the same form, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your theme needs to reference the custom fields from the backend, they aren't included in

```
<?php the_content();?>
```

EG: If the custom field is a text field your theme will need something like:

```
<?php the_field('name_of_custom_field'); ?>
```

I'd suggest you look at the docs located here:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/

Comment: so I would need to make that change everytime I create something on the site? and for 'name_of_custom_field' do i replace that with the 'contact_form_group'?

Comment: @user372204 If your ACF field is using a group then it's a bit more configuration required, I would suggest that you look through their [group docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/), then probably make a custom template for the page you require these fields to be on. ACF Pro is an incredibly powerful plugin, and probably the best WordPress plugin ever developed IMO, as a WP developer myself I've not built a site without it in almost a decade. If I were you, i'd log in to your account there and ask for assistance in their forum as the support you'll receive is great

Comment: Does that mean i would have to create a template every time i create a page?

Comment: You only need to create a template for a page which has a different layout, the page template can be reused on any pages which share the same layout. If you are not a developer I would strongly suggest you hire one, failing that look at the [Docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/) which I have pointed you to 3 times now. Good luck